# Can you declare order of Attribute directives in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have the [following simple pluner](http://embed.plnkr.co/oTySMLmVj6z6xdE94zEk/) where I am trying to use Attribute Directives to add (or override) different options within my application. The problem I am seeing is that the order in which these directives are initialized does not match the order of the directives in the DOM element.

So even though I declare them in the order...

`<div jgMoreOptions jgOptions [options]="options">`

They seem to take the order declared in the Application declaration here...

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ 
    App,
    OptionsDirective,
    MoreOptionsDirective,
  ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
```

This is a problem if I have multiple implementations that want the directives loaded in different orders.

Is there a way to declare order of the directives in the tag itself?

[Here is an example with both directives in a diff order](http://embed.plnkr.co/Yd5njSSztKdmO5CPZgfJ/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order is explicitly **not defined**

You need to writer your code in a way, so that the order doesn't matter.

Comment: This doesn't work for my example because of options overwriting other options. Is there anyway to write a wrapper or somehow be more explicit? In the previous versions of angular we were using an eval expression and I want to avoid that.

Comment: Perhaps a pipe is a better options for your use case, like `[options]="options | jgMoreOptions | jgOptiosn"`

Comment: Not sure I follow that snippet any chance of getting an example plunker? I added the second plunker to be a little clearer what I am looking for, let me know if you need me to expand on it.

Comment: A pipe is only to manipulate values. The `@HostBinding('style.background-color')` can't be achieved using a pipe.

Comment: I think you might be on to something I am just confused how I would pipe the output of a directive. OR are you saying if I just create the jgMoreOptions as another simple object it will merge the options automagically using the pipes

Comment: A pipe is just a function that takes an input value (parameter) and returns an output value (`return xxx;`). What the pipe returns is then passed to `[options]`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136375/discussion-between-jackie-and-gunter-zochbauer).